# How to manage state in ios objective c

Tags: ios, iphone

I’m new in iOS development. My question is, I’ve two view controllers.

> viewController - A viewController - B

Now, if i killed the app from the viewController - A and than relaunch the app. than app must be open the viewController - A. and if i killed the app from the viewController - B and than relaunch the app. than app must be open the viewController - B.

Can anyone help me, I’ve done the RND but can not find the proper solution.

Thanks

Comment: Start by reading this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html

Comment: There's also  a tutorial here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/117471/state-restoration-tutorial

Comment: (The tutorial is in Swift, but the classes and methods used should be the same in Objective-C).

Comment: in which language you tried this

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a sharedDelegate in AppDelegate.m file

```c
+(AppDelegate *)sharedDelegate {
    return (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

2. in AppDelegate.h

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currentViewContoller;
```

3. when push to any contoller then set AppDelegate's currentViewContoller to new VC

```c
YourViewController *vc=[[YourViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].currentViewContoller = NSStringFromClass([YourViewController class]);
```

4. now when app is terminated

```c
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].currentViewContoller forKey:@"currentVC"];
}
```

5. now when app launched first time check previous controller when app terminated

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSString *string=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentVC"];
```

and push this class

```
    UIViewController *object = [[NSClassFromString(string) alloc] init...];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`applicationWillTerminate` you can use but it will only get called if user quit app from `forground` If your app is in background and then user quit app then `applicationWillTerminate` will not get called.

So, you have to take care of `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

So, when app enter in background (i.e call `applicationDidEnterBackground` ) or call `applicationWillTerminate` save state(your current VC) in your `user defaults`.

Now in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` set that view controller as `rootviewcontroller` or whatever way that you want to manage it.

reference : [Apple documentation for applicationWillTerminate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate)

PS : You should not manage app like this. It is horrible way!! If possible then run your app as normal flow!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Storyboards` you can use the `Restoration Identifier` to communicate the App which controller to launch as first

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html